# WireMock fails with NoSuchMethodError HttpServletResponse.getHeader

Tags: java, maven, jetty, wiremock

I'm trying to use WireMock in my JUnit tests to mock calls to an external API.

```
public class ExampleWiremockTest {

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(9999);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/bin/sillyServlet"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody("Hello WireMock!")
            )
        );

    }

    @Test
    public void testNothing() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("http")
            .setHost("localhost")
            .setPort(9999)
            .setPath("/bin/sillyServlet")
            .build();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        assertThat(body, is("Hello WireMock!"));
    }

}
```

The code compiles but when I run my test, WireMock throws an HTTP 500 that seems to be caused by an inconsistency in the underlying Servlet API version.

```
Running com.example.core.ExampleWiremockTest
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @1030ms
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@ef9296d{/__admin,null,AVAILABLE}
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@659a969b{/,null,AVAILABLE}
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.NetworkTrafficServerConnector - Started NetworkTrafficServerConnector@723d73e1{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9999}
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @1168ms
[qtp436546048-16] INFO /__admin - RequestHandlerClass from context returned com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AdminRequestHandler. Normalized mapped under returned 'null'
[qtp436546048-20] INFO / - RequestHandlerClass from context returned com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler. Normalized mapped under returned 'null'
[qtp436546048-20] WARN wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - Error for /bin/sillyServlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:322)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[qtp436546048-20] WARN wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /bin/sillyServlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[qtp436546048-20] WARN wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - Could not send response error 500: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.NetworkTrafficServerConnector - Stopped NetworkTrafficServerConnector@723d73e1{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9999}
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@659a969b{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
[main] INFO wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@ef9296d{/__admin,null,UNAVAILABLE}
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.577 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.core.ExampleWiremockTest
```

I do have other libraries in my classpath that rely on different versions of Jetty, which I suppose is the cause of the problem.

WireMock uses Jetty 9.2.13, I also have a transitive dependency on Cobertura, which relies on 6.1.14

I was originally trying to use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I switched to the standalone Jar version, hoping it would help me avoid the conflict but the result is exactly the same.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, in the question, one of the libraries I was using had a dependency on Cobertura, which in turn introducde a dependency on Servlet API 2.5 (both as a transitive dependency via an older verison of Jetty and a direct dependency).

[image: Cobertura dependency]

Excluding the artifact from the original dependency (the one dependent on cobertura) allowed me to run my test successfully.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cognifide.slice</groupId>
    <artifactId>slice-core-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slice.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should be excluding that older version of Jetty, not the servlet-api specifically.

Answer (score 7):

For those who lend to this ticket while using `wiremock-jre8` (with transitive Jetty 9) when upgrading to Java 17/Spring Boot 3/Spring 6 having `NoSuchMethodError: NetworkTrafficServerConnector.addNetworkTrafficListener`:
Migrate to [`wiremock-standalone`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone)

See more: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/1760#issuecomment-1234404609

Answer (score 6):

Check your servlet-api version, you likely are using an old version.

Both of those methods were added in Servlet 3.0

- [`HttpServletResponse.getHeader(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-)
- [`HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isAsyncStarted--)

You probably have the Servlet 2.5 (or Servlet 2.4) jar in your classpath.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. One of the libraries I'm using has a dependency on `cobertura`, which has a dependency on `servlet-api-2.5`. I was looking for a way to work around this problem.

Comment: Not possible.  You have to select a single servlet-api for your project, you cannot have multiple.   Since you are using Jetty 9.2.x, I would recommend using Servlet 3.1.  Cobertura wont care that a newer servlet api exists, but everything else will care about the older servlet-api.

Comment: Excluding the implicit servlet API dependency introduced by Cobertura did the trick, see the other answer.